# SPFx create New Experience UI List/Library View with my own content

Tags: spfx-webparts

Been playing with this SPFx for some hours now, done the Tutorials, and.. I am not impressed.

I was expecting SPFx to be a library so that I could create New Experiences (Library View, List View) by supplying my own (List) data.

Sofar I see a fancy Content Editor WebPart, requiring more tools than a brain-surgeon

Do I still have to built all that UI sh* myself?

Yes, I know about Fabric and ng-FabricOfficeNgSomething, but Microsoft has built all the NewExperiences UI stuff and I presume "*Sharing is Caring*" goes both ways.

(*if this is a Roadmap question, sorry, don't read those, I have to work to pay the bills*)

Comment: You do have access to SharePoint data using the REST APIs with which you can get the data you want and build your web part.

If you are asking for a list view web part or building custom list forms or building client-side JSLink solutions - yes, those are in the roadmap. 
In the essence of sharing, we do have Office UI Fabric React - https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react - that has all the controls we use across Office 365. You can use these controls in your web part, as long as they are based off of react.

Comment: I have been doing Dashboards on REST endpoints since SP2010. And I know when to use React (which in 95% of uses is totally not needed, but the result of a developer wanting to do 'cool' stuff ) .. Sorry.. but this new toy feels a bit like giving your wife a Formula-I car for doing the shopping on saturday

Comment: If you find the current approaches to be feasible, please keep using them. SharePoint Framework is huge step forward for both Microsoft and customers on how they build applications in SharePoint for both on-premises and online. We have optimization both on the server side and client side to enable developers host myriad of applications. We start today with web parts.

Comment: though you cant create a view with SPFx, you can create one with PowerAppps..

Comment: Looking forward to the Future; Present day with a Wiki site that says Mobile First and a Hello World Page that takes 4 MB (a Blank WebPart page in Classic is 2.6 MB) is not impressive

Comment: Unfortunately, I agree, #spfx IS way too complicated and ***loaded with tons*** of dependencies just to get a ***VERY complex*** 'Hello World'.... but moving on.... working thru the mud for the moment.

Comment: I now call it SPFudge instead of SPFx. Decided to leave it, let others clear the mud and then move in... (have done Internet front-end for 26 years ...*I know when to hold them and know when to run*)